# Compare proportions between two groups on multi-categorical variable

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, proportion, case-control-study

I have a case-control study where I have a variable measures social deprivation into 5 categories 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want to compare if there is any significant different between the case and controls for each category.

My data is in following format:

```
           1     2      3      4      5 
Cases      1813  1754   1850   1503   1601
Controls   50021 55154  49932  56245  51022
```

I know I can do a chi-square test for the cases + proportions to test for significance of how cases end up in the groups they are in by doing `chisq.test(Cases)`. But this looks at what the expected proportion should be amongst cases. Is there a way I can take the cases in category 1 and compare to controls in category 1? I had thought maybe I could transform my data in percentages and directly compare the cases and controls per category using a chi-square test?